# Сравнение двух множеств чисел

Tags: алгоритм

По заданию получаем 2 массива чисел.
Нужно написать функцию, которая проверяет похожие ли массивы.(массивы похожие, если совпадают множества чисел в них).
Нужно использовать сортировку слиянием и обменом.

Как я понимаю - нужно отсортировать массивы используя разные сортировки, а после поэлементно проверять совпадение массивов. Но в таком случае сортировка не имеет смысла.

Comment: Почему не имеет? Допустим, исходные массивы `[1, 2, 3, 4]` и `[1, 4, 3, 2]`.

Comment: Сортировка имеет смысл. Без сортировки вам надо искать каждый элемент 1го массива во всем втором, перебором. А если они отсортированы - то просто сверять N-й элемент 1го с N-нм второго, а не искать по всему массиву

Answer (score 1):

Как мы можем сравнить два объекта, если они имеют несколько представлений? Например, равны ли два рациональных числа 4/10 и 12/30? Совпадают ли корни уравнений x<sup>2</sup>+2x+4 и 5x<sup>2</sup>+10x+20? Совпадают ли множества [1; 2; 3] и [1; 3; 2]?

Если решать задачу «в лоб», то объекты не совпадают, но в действительности 4/10 == 12/30. Лобовое решение неправильно.

Для того, чтобы решать такие задачи, объекты приводят к единому виду, который часто называют *нормальным*, а само приведение — *нормализацией*. Дроби сокращают, все коэффициенты квадратного уравнения делят на коэффициент при x<sup>2</sup>, а массивы сортируют.

Иногда возможны разные способы нормализации. Если числа у вас небольшие, вместо массива вы можете хранить их в битовом массиве. Например, для множество чисел от 0 до 31 можно хранить в одном тридцатидвухбитном целом числе, установив соответствующие биты.

Тогда сравнение множеств сведётся к сравнению двух целых чисел. Но, если наши числа могут быть произвольными, битовый массив может оказаться слишком большим. В этом случае хорошо работает сортировка. Сравнение двух отсортированных массивов сводится к простому попарному сравнению с временной сложностью O(N). Это, конечно, не очень быстро, но гораздо быстрее, чем попарное сравнение сортированных массивов со сложностью O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

Смотря на каком языке это делать. На php например можно сразу без сортировки сделать array_diff и сравнить его count() с count() первоначальных массивов, они если меньше нужного значения (например если меньше 20%) то да массивы содержат одинаковые значения на 80%.
Если же вручную надо проделать сверку то да, тут другая ситуация, но тогда можно подсмотреть как работаю похожие функции в каком-то языке, т.к. самому оптимальный алгоритм сходу сложно придумать.